# git pull on server using hook after I push locally

Tags: git, githooks

I'm working with html & css files locally. After I `git push` the files to my server (into a bare directory which I created with `mkdir bare_repos/mysite && cd bare_repos/mysite && git init --bare`), I don't want to have to ssh into the server, go into my `~/public_html/mysite` directory and type `git pull`. I think a hook should do this but I'm not sure how?

The files in my `bare_repos/mysite/hooks/` directory are: `applypatch-msg.sample, post-update.sample, pre-commit.sample, pre-rebase.sample, prepare-commit-msg.sample, commit-msg.sample, pre-applypatch.sample, pre-push.sample, pre-receive.sample, update.sample`

Which file should I edit and what should be added to it? I want to be able to push from my local machine and then simply see the changes on website from my browser (no ssh'ing needed)

Answer (score 1):

You need `update` or `post-receive` hook enabled in your bare repository. Search for some examples: [post-receive](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithooks%5D+post-receive), [update](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithooks%5D+update).

The hooks must be named exactly `update` or `post-receive` (not `update.sample` or `post-receive.sh`, for example). They also must be executable.

Answer (score 1):

I followed instructions [here](http://toroid.org/git-website-howto). I created a `post-receive` file and added:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/username/public_html/mysite git checkout -f
```

Then I made it executable (`chmod +x post-receive`)

Now when I `git push`, changes are automatically seen on my website.